How can I access current Point and Figure [PnF] chart parameters in Pinescript v5?
I want to code an indicator based on Point and Figure in Pinescript v5.
Once the chart type is PnF, how could I access the Box Size and Reversal Amount values to store them in variables?
I want to automate this instead of entering these values manually.
Any idea how to do this?
Thank you!
I've searched in the manual and there's nothing related to this.
The function pointfigure() doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
